# Connected components mod p

Tags: number-theory, commutative-algebra, arithmetic-geometry

Let $R = \mathbb Q_p (\mu_p)$ and $k = \mathbb F_p$ it's residue field. Consider $A = R[x]/(x^p-1)$. Then, I believe $A = \prod_{i=0}^{p-1}R[x]/(x-\zeta_p^i)$ so $\operatorname{Spec}A$ has $p$ connected components.

On the other hand, after reducing mod $p$, $A_k = k[x]/(x-1)^p$ so this has only one connected component. This seems to contradict what Conrad says here: https://mathoverflow.net/a/16136/58001, in the paragraph beginning "OK, now assume R is a complete...".

In particular, he claims that for a complete local ring, the connected components of a finite scheme over $R$ and over the residue field are in bijection.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $A = \prod_{i=0}^{p-1}R[x]/(x-\zeta_p^i)$: are you sure?

Comment: No! But shouldn't it follow from the Chinese Remainder theorem?

Comment: Oh, I see. The ideals don't generate 1. That was stupid of me...